# how to pass the address.pk as a parameter after the form has been successfully submitted in a django form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I created an address form in a Django project and I have also created an  AddressDetailView in views.py. When a user successfully submits the address form, I  want to redirect the user into the address_details.html by passing the address.pk as the parameter. But I don't know how to pass that parameter. I keep getting an error as shown belong and I don't know how to fix it.

this is the models.py for the address model

```
    route_name = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='NULL')
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    make_initial_location = models.BooleanField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('address-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

this is the Address form in forms.py:

```
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['route_name','name', 'city','area','location','make_initial_location']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.username = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

this is the Address creation view in views.py, this is where i wrote the code for redirecting to address-detail, it shows me that the error is in **return redirect('address-detail')** :

```
@login_required
def  AddressCreateVeiw(request):
    form = AddressCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddressCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your address has been successfully created!')
           return redirect('address-detail')
    return render(request, 'blog/address_form.html', {'form': form})
```

this is the URL paths for address form and address-detail HTML pages:

```
 path('address/<int:pk>/', AddressDetailView.as_view(), name='address-detail'),
    path('address/new/', views.AddressCreateVeiw, name='address-create')
]
```

address_form html page:

````
    {% csrf_token %}
         <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Registration Page</legend>
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button class="button" type="submit"> Register</button>
</form>```

this is the address_detail.html page:
``` <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Details of <b>{{ object.name }} </b> address</legend>
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'route-addresses' address.route_name %}">Route: {{ object.route_name }} </a>
            <br>
            <small class="text-muted">Click on the route to see all addresses added to it. </small>

        </div>
        <p><b>City:</b> {{ object.city }}</p>
        <p><b>Area: </b> {{ object.area }}</p>
        <p><b>Location: </b> {{ object.location }}</p>
        <p class="text-muted">Is Initial Location: {{object.make_initial_location}}</p>
        {% if object.username == user %}
        <div>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'address-update' object.id %}"> Update</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'address-delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

</article>
````

After I submit my address form, I get this error:
[image: error]

Comment: `form_valid` is not a method for a `Form`, but for a `View` with a `FormMixin` There is also no `self.request` in a form, since forms are request-unaware.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a parameter for the `pk` URL parameter:

```
@login_required
def AddressCreateVeiw(request):
    form = AddressCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddressCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.username = request.user
            instance = form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your address has been successfully created!')
            return redirect('address-detail', pk=instance.pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/address_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that a `Form` (or `ModelForm`) has no `form_valid` method, class-based views with a [**`FormMixin`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin) have this. A form furthermore has no access to the `request` object, since forms are request-unaware.

Since you defined a `.get_absolute_url()` method on the `Address` model, you can also simply call the [**`redirect(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) with the `instance:

```
@login_required
def AddressCreateVeiw(request):
    form = AddressCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddressCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.username = request.user
            instance = form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your address has been successfully created!')
            return redirect(instance)
    return render(request, 'blog/address_form.html', {'form': form})
```